# Beginner help need for python script

Tags: python

I created some code that takes an inputted password and if it meets certain criteria it is either accepted or denied and a new password is given to the user. However, the code never seems to return as password accepted. pls help

I need it to be able to return as password accepted if the entered password is above five characters, has no repetitions and has at least one symbol and number.

This is my code:

```
import random
import string
import re
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

passw_var = tk.StringVar()

def new_password(length):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        newpass = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
        label6 = tk.Label (root, text="Here is your new Password: " + newpass)
        canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=label6)
        label6.pack()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()
root.title("Spring HT Project")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Password Checker')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Enter your Password:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 80, window=label2)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Result:")
label3.config(font=("helvetica", 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 150, window=label3)


entry = tk.Entry (root, textvariable = passw_var, font = ('calibre',10,'normal'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=entry)

def validate(password):
    if len(password) < 5: 
      return False  

    elif re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:  
      return False
    

    elif re.search('"[£$%^&*()!?<>@+=#~:;]', password) is None:  
      return False

    else:
        for i in range(len(password) - 1):  
            for j in range(i + 1, len(password)):  
                if len(re.findall(r"(" + password[i:j] + password[i:j] + r")+",password))> 0:  
                    return False 
    return True

def checker():
  password=passw_var.get()
  if validate(password):  #if the password goes through the function and returns true, then it is accepted
      label5 = tk.Label (root, text="Password Accepted")
      canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=label5)
      label5.pack()
    
  else:  
      new_password(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the test

```
else:
        for i in range(len(password) - 1):  
            for j in range(i + 1, len(password)):  
                if len(re.findall(r"(" + password[i:j] + password[i:j] + r")+",password))> 0:  
                    return False
```

Is checking whether a character is duplicated in the password and always returning False.
It would be simpler to test as follows

```
else:
   for char in password:
      if password.count(char) > 1:
        return False
```